# NpgsqlTimeout timeout when trying to migrate

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a project in .Net 5 the database used is Postgres. I'm using a docker-compose file database, but when I run the `dotnet ef database update` command I get the following error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   ....
Exception while connecting
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: Guilherme
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXXX
      POSTGRES_DB: BuiltCode

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

Connection String:

```
"PostgreSql": "Username=Guilherme;Password=XXXX;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=BuiltCode;"
```

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add under `db` section:

```yaml
ports:
- '5432:5432'
```